# Log4j 2 not logging out %throwable

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, stack-trace, printstacktrace

I want to print the stack trace when logging errors using this basic Log4j log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="throwable: %throwable"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This is all I have in my dependencies:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When I run this (asdf doesn't exist):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
        try {
            new FileInputStream("asdf");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error(e);
        }
    }
}
```

my output is

```
throwable:
```

and I want something like this:

```
throwable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: asdf (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

documentation from PatternLayout at: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout
default (%throwable) should log the entire stack trace

Any help would be great!

Edit: I am using Java 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Logger.error(Object)`. All logging methods with a single object parameter only log the `toString()` value of that object, even if it is a Throwable. In your case the appender pattern does not contain `%m`/`%msg`/`%message` so you are only seeing "throwable:" in the console output.
If we add the message to the pattern the output is:

```
throwable: java.io.FileNotFoundException: asdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

This is a pretty common pitfall when using Log4j2 and sadly it appears this [won't change in the future](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-86).

To properly log the exception and its stack trace you can either use one of the logging methods with separate `Throwable` parameter, e.g. `Logger.error(String, Throwable)`, or you can use `Logger.catching(Level, Throwable)`. However, the logging methods with message parameter should be preferred since they allow you to describe the context. Otherwise you might have a hard time finding out where the log message was actually created.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Ended up using logger.error("Some message to it", e);

Comment: FWIW, you can also use logger.atError().withThrowable(e).log("");  Although it is always a good practice to include some description about the error I might consider adding a log() method that requires no parameters.